# Write command to gnome terminal with QProcess

Tags: qt, command, execute, qprocess, gnome-terminal

I am trying to write an application with Qt in Netbeans. I am able to open the gnome terminal (in Ubuntu), however I can't seem to get a command to be executed in the terminal once it is open, e.g. to execute the 'ls' command.

Can anyone perhaps help me with some code to execute the ls command in the gnome terminal once it is opened? I am opening the terminal with the following code:

```
QProcess *proc = new QProcess(this);
proc->start("gnome-terminal");
if (!proc->waitForStarted()) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `-e` argument:

```
proc->start("gnome-terminal -e 'ls'");
```

To keep the window open, go to *Edit > Profile Preferences > Command > When command exits* and change to *Hold the terminal open*.

Comment: Is there any way to 'write' the "-e ls" command to an already open terminal? For instance if I would like to open the terminal and then perform a series of commands programatically in a step-wise manner.

Comment: Not easily. You can try to write directly to shell or terminal process like `echo "ls\n" > /proc/<PID>/fd/0` but I doubt that it will work.